# PHP extension “mcrypt” must be loaded.

Tags: magento

I am installing magento CMS, and am trying to install the files. I am getting this error when I am in configuration mode.

```
PHP extension “mcrypt” must be loaded.
```

I am used to activating this extension by removing `;` from extension=php_mcrypt.dll in php.in, but the problem is still present.

Why would this be happening and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Restart server. Also check that you are editing the right php.ini. If you are using wamp for example there are a few php.ini files in there

Comment: i will edit php.iniand still error

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to restart the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Run php file with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and check whether there is a mcrypt extension, if no check path for right php.ini file.

Comment: Send screen from phpinfo ;)